# Change DateTime format and store it as a DateFormat

Tags: c#, datetime

How should I change a DateTime format in C# and store it into another DateTime object?

Eg.: I have a DateTime object which stores a datetime value in "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm" format. I want it to store the same date at "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" format on a DateTime object. I'm able to set the new formatted date into a string, but that's not what I need.

Any suggestions? Cheers!

Comment: DateTime objects don't have any format. Only conversions from DateTime to String have a format.

Comment: Why do you want to store it as a string?  You should only convert it to a string for display/reporting purposes, otherwise, it should stay a `DateTime`.  `DateTime` variables are *not* stored in a particular format...what you're seeing is only how it's rendered in your IDE.

Comment: What do you mean, store the format? If you're not storing it as a string, then you shouldn't need to worry about the format

Comment: I understand. Should I work on the culture of my project?

Comment: Store it as DateTime and choose the format at the time of rendering

Comment: In .NET a `DateTime` structure stores the underlying date as the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar. There's no notion of formats. Asking about changing a format of a DateTime object in .NET makes strictly no sense.

Comment: The point is, it doesn't matter.  You're worrying about seeing the date/time in your development environment...it's not really important.  It's just a bunch of data in memory.  If you're concerned with how your users will see it in your application, then you need to convert it to a string for display and only then do you need to worry about culture, etc.

Comment: A `DateTime` has no format, that's a good thing, so you don't need to care about it. Store it always as `DateTime`  and do the conversion where you need to display it.

Comment: I understood it, guys. Thanks! So, if I change my project culture, will it affect how data is seen? I'm really new to C# and I'm still studying it.

Comment: @StefanoGuimarãesFalce If you change the culture it will affect the result of `.ToString()` or `.ToShortDate()` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give format to your date type like this:

Do which one you waant

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);
    String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
    String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
    String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
    String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
    String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
    String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
    String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
    String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
    String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
    String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone

String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9/3/2008 16:05:07" - english (en-US)
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9.3.2008 16:05:07" - german (de-DE)

String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);            // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"

// day/month names
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

// two/four digit year
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);            // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"
String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"                         ShortTime
String.Format("{0:d}", dt);  // "3/9/2008"                        ShortDate
String.Format("{0:T}", dt);  // "4:05:07 PM"                      LongTime
String.Format("{0:D}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008"          LongDate
String.Format("{0:f}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05 PM"  LongDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:F}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05:07 PM" FullDateTime
String.Format("{0:g}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05 PM"                ShortDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:G}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05:07 PM"             ShortDate+LongTime
String.Format("{0:m}", dt);  // "March 09"                        MonthDay
String.Format("{0:y}", dt);  // "March, 2008"                     YearMonth
String.Format("{0:r}", dt);  // "Sun, 09 Mar 2008 16:05:07 GMT"   RFC1123
String.Format("{0:s}", dt);  // "2008-03-09T16:05:07"             SortableDateTime
String.Format("{0:u}", dt);  // "2008-03-09 16:05:07Z"            UniversalSortableDateTime
```

Comment: You're welcome. friend don,t forget voting up answer  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt");
```

this should help